# How to load multi block of SPA page simultaneously (ng-view or ui-view)

Tags: angularjs, uiview

Can any one advise on how to handle the scenario listed below..
I want to load a page block\section by block\section. The spa page has four sections\block, which need to loaded separately. Multiple  ajax request will be done which will return back json result and then will be blocks will be rendered.

I believe UI Router(ui-view) vs ng-view can be used to handled nested view. But how to handled loading of multiple parts of a page(views ) simultaneously

Comment: `ng-view` can't handle nested views, it should be used once per app

Comment: Really not clear what the issue is. Have you read the docs and tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple views when using [UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), it's a third party router for angular that replaces the default on. Try going over their documents and [user-guide](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki), [this section](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) describes a use-case similar to yours